# $\sum a_n$ converges, converge $\sum (a_n)/(1-a_n)$ too?

Tags: analysis

Suppose that 0 < $a_n$ < 1 and you know that $\sum a_n$ converges. Is it right that $\sum (a_n)/(1 - a_n)$ converges too? I don't know how I can answer this. I have already considered the comparison test, but I don't exactly know how to work that out. Can somebody give a hint?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Given that $\sum a_n$ converges, you know that $a_n\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$. Therefore, what can you say about $1-a_n$ as $n\to \infty$?

Comment: That will obviously go to $1$

Comment: Right, now you have to write it formally. I suggest you using the $n_0,\varepsilon$ definition of limit and then use the comparison test.

Answer (score 1):

$a_n \gt 0$, $ a_n\not=1,$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z+}$.

$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n= 0.$

There is $n_0$ such that $a_n \lt 1/2$ for $n\ge n_0.$

For $n \gt n_0:$

$\dfrac{a_n}{1- a_n} \le 2a_n.$

$\sum_{i=1}^{k} 2a_i$ converges.

$\rightarrow: $

1)$S_k := \sum_{i=1}^{k} \dfrac{a_i}{1-a_i}$ is bounded above

2) $S_k$ is monotonically increasing ,

hence convergent.